# Hadoop Name node recovery in CDH3 cluster

Tags: hadoop

I am using CDH3 Cloudera Pseudo distributed mode cluster.It was working fine before. but currently i am   not able to do any hadoop commands,hive queries,pig scripts.

Looks like the  namenode gets corrupted.

I tried sudo jps and found that namenode daemon is not running.

It only shows
    DataNode

```
Jps
RunJar
HMaster
SecondaryNamenode
```

What is the root cause here? How do i recover my name node?

Comment: Try restarting all the nodes, sometimes formatting namenode will do.

Comment: How to format namenode. Can you give me the command. Also I am using Cloudera CDH3 Cluster(single node)

Comment: hadoop namenode -format